# Compile shared library from asm code with current sources

Tags: compiling, assembly, ld, nasm

I just did some basic functions in asm that I compile in a shared library.
Like :

```
BITS 64
            global foo
            section .text
foo:
            mov rax, 1
            ret
```

I compiled with :

```
nasm -f elf64 foo.S -o foo.o && gcc -shared foo.o -o libfoo.so
```

I have a main of test :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int foo();

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", foo());
  return (0);
}
```

If I compiled it with the foo.o directly, everything works well. But if I compiled like this :

```
gcc main.c -L. -lfoo
```

I would get this error :

```
/usr/.../bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol `foo' are not defined
```

I thought it was because the prototype is not declared, but I recompiled foo.o with a lib.h file containing the prototype, and the same problem occurs.

Is that I must complete another section of the elf file?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `[]` around `BITS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the `foo` symbol corresponds to a [function](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html#section-6.6):

```
[BITS 64]
            global foo:function
            section .text
foo:
            mov rax, 1
            ret
```